# How to re-use a common page header to multiple reports using subreports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to use the same page header info in all my reports. For this,
--- I created the page header in a report and saved it
--- Now, in my report i added a sub report and chose the above report (step 1) report to use as sub report but it retrieves only the table and not the PAGE HEADER ?
---Could anybody give a solution?

Comment: Is it an option to use a report template instead? That would be a lot easier than playing with subreports. The downside is that a modification in the header will have to be applied to all reports.

Comment: Sub-reports don't show page headers or footers.  By Design.

If you can explain why you want page headers and footers in your sub-report (I assume because the sub reports span multiple pages?)  you could ask a more specific question.

Comment: @trubs, In the page header, say, if i need to add the Company name and address, and all my reports have to display this by default. In this case, i tried to retrieve the page header info via the sub report.